# BufferedReader.lines().foreach() never terminates

Tags: java, java-io, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to read a HTTP request from a Bufferedreader, that gets `Socket.getInputStream()` as input. However, when I use `Bufferedreader.lines().foreach()`, it never terminates and it just gets stuck.

My code (simplified):

```
Socket socket = new ServerSocket(9090);
Socket newConnection = socket.accept();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(newConnection.getInputStream()));
reader.lines().forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
```

Comment: I suspect it is blocking waiting for data from the socket that is never going to come.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read more about the HTTP 1.1 protocol. Requests aren't terminated by end of stream. They are terminated by exhausting the byte count in the Content-length header, or of the cumulative chunks if chunked transfer mode is in use. If they were exhausted by end of stream, you could never send a response.

Comment: +1 Good answer. I missed the reference to HTTP when I first read the question.

Comment: Requests do not necessarily have a `Content-length`. The may simply have empty content. Since the code from the question seems to read the request *header* it’s worth noting that the header ends with the first empty line. And that `HTTP/1.1` allows sending multiple requests through one connection.

Comment: " If they were exhausted by end of stream, you could never send a response." Is not fully true. Http connection go over a TCP connection, a TCP connection can be half terminated when one side send a FIN, the other side ACK'ed the FIN, but is still sending data. In java, this can be done using `Socket.shutdownOutput`. You are probable confusing with a normal socket close that closes both at once

Answer (score -2):

Try creating your socket with parameter-less constructor and use [connect()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#connect%28java.net.SocketAddress,%20int%29) method with port and timeout parameter. This will prevent endless freeze.

Comment: The OP's code is the *server* side, not the client side, of the connection.